# stream music interrupts after 4,5 seconds

Tags: android, audio

I'm using this method to play sounds:

```
int streamVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mSoundPool.play(mSoundPoolMap.get(index), streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, 0, 1f);
```

I have not problem playing short sounds. But if I play music that takes longer, it interrupts at the 4,5 second. As per usual no error or notification is shown.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Soundpool plays only first 5 secs of file. Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13377604/soundpool-plays-only-first-5-secs-of-file-why)

Comment: strangely the bash scripters and sql masters are the most active here

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a [SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) this is pretty much the basic behaviour, its intended for small clips only.

[Soundpool plays only first 5 secs of file. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13377604/soundpool-plays-only-first-5-secs-of-file-why)

I had the same issue and if you want to play longer sounds you will need to use the [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try reducing the sample rate from 44khz to 32khz or lower.