# can the media player in android play a music file in the project files?

Tags: android

I need to know if the media player can access an mp3 file that is stored in `getFilesDir()`
if it is possible, tell me please

Comment: `getFilesDir()` != `project files` former is external to the apk, latter will be internal (and unmodifiable) once it is compiled.

Comment: ok I need `getFilesDir()` one ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `getFilesDir()`, since that allows editing of your files and it is local to your app. However upon app uninstallation, this directory will be deleted.

If you don't need your files modified, the `res/raw` folder works nicely.

Comment: ok there is no problem. All I want is to play an mp3 file that is in getFilesDir() ... can I ??

Comment: Where is the mp3 coming from? If it's from your own app, there is no point in using getFilesDir(). MAke a new folder in the res folder called `raw` and put your mp3 there. To access it, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162230/how-do-i-play-an-mp3-in-the-res-raw-folder-of-my-android-app) SO question may help.

Comment: no, I downloaded the mp3 file using the application and saved it in files directory. and now I need to play the music file using MediaPlayer. is there any way ??

Comment: Ah, that's completely different. That is on the world-readable/writable storage (so the internal and external sd card). Something like [this](http://android-er.blogspot.ca/2010/07/play-mp3-in-sd-card-using-androids.html) should help. If the mp3 is on the external sd, you may need the [READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) permission.