# React to an incoming message in android

Tags: android

I have got the project to develop an app where my android phone rings loud when it is in silent mode by an incoming SMS. I am NOT asking for any source codes.  I just want to know how to proceed with this .

Comment: Implement broadcast reciever for the incoming SMS receiver.

Answer (score 2):

u need to register receiver for incoming sms

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();


           //play ringtone here

}
```

}

for playing ringtone refer [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) & [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidMedia/article.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162230/how-do-i-play-an-mp3-in-the-res-raw-folder-of-my-android-app)

*note: dont forget to include permission in Manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

and the receiver part:

```
<receiver android:name=".listener.SmsListener">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) to listen for SMS events. These tutorials should help you get started:

- http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android
- http://www.anddev.org/recognize-react_on_incoming_sms-t295.html

Comment: how to get gps location through sms?

Answer (score 0):

UrbanAirship is a good thing. It will give you notifications as well !