# playing a mp3 file in android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm using the following code to play a mp3 from raw folder but nothing happens!
can anyone help me? thanks

```
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(ShapesActivity.this, R.raw.circle);
    mp.start();
    mp.release();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I play an mp3 in the res/raw folder of my android app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162230/how-do-i-play-an-mp3-in-the-res-raw-folder-of-my-android-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out @TuomasK you release the media before playing it. You should implement `OnCompletionListener` to release MediaPlayer properly.

You can do it like this:

```
MediaPlayer mMp = MediaPlayer.create(ShapesActivity.this, R.raw.circle);
mMp.start();

mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.reset();
        mp.release();
    };
});
```

Comment: thanks guys. I tried this, I also removed the release but it still isn't working

Comment: Do you have a file `/res/raw/circle.mp3`, or is Logcat showing something?

Answer (score 0):

You are releasing the mediaplayer right after you start it, so the sound doesn't play. You need to remove `mp.release()`