# Android Studio raw file error background music

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have downloaded a background music and put it on a raw file, but Android Studio won't see it. I pressed something wrong and now raw is now seen as a Java class, but still, my mp3 file can't be seen. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: try to rebuild and clean project

Comment: How can I do this ?

Comment: It's just `R.raw.sound`... You don't need the extension

Comment: Remove the `.mp3` part from the parameter

Comment: It still appears with red color

Comment: Well, that's correct, so you have some other problem with your resources - Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162230/how-do-i-play-an-mp3-in-the-res-raw-folder-of-my-android-app

Comment: @cricket_007 Already tried this, but unsuccessfully. Maybe rebuilding and clean project will work ?

Comment: Not unless some other XML file, for example, has an error... You need to try and compile your code and look at the errors

Comment: @cricket_007 I solved the error, but the mp3 don't start when I start the application. How should I save the mp3? I just copy and pasted into the raw folder.

Comment: That's the only way I know how to save mp3 into the project